# How to setup VPN from on-premises database to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, vpc, google-cloud-vpn

I want to be able to connect from on premises database to google cloud.
I have VPC set, external IP address and VPN but not connected yet.
Is there something I missed? Do I have to create a compute engine first?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please start with these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to first read [this link](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview) which is the cloud VPN overview to mainly understand the type of VPN that you are creating for this setup and then setup your VPN.

In [this other link](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/how-to/interop-guides) you will find some guides to setup the VPN with devices such as Cisco or even other cloud providers. I hope you find this links useful since your question doesn't have much information to better understand if you have any error message or kind of peer device you're using for this set up

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Before creating cloud vpn should create VM-Compute Engine or not necessary?